# Internship technical task question, revising mistakes

Tags: interviewing, internship, mistakes

So I was given a technical task to do from home as part of the interviewing process for an internship and submit the task to them when I'm finished. I submitted the task, then I realized I made a mistake when interpreting the task and asked for a resubmission and resubmitted it. I now realize I made another mistake. Should I wait for a response pointing out my mistake or ask for another resubmission which is the final revision? Have I dug my hole too deep? I just don't know how it looks on the employers end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way you can know whether you've finished yourself.

I would resubmit it anyway with the corrections with the explanation that "even if it's too late, I do not like to let incorrect work stand and so wanted to offer a completed, corrected version."

That may impress someone and it may not. But I think it also is a good practice to not let incorrect work stand.

Comment: I know I can't know I finished it myself but this last revision Im 99% sure is what they are asking. But thanks for that input!